# Setup multiple private repositories cpanel

Tags: django, git, github, cpanel

How can I setup access for multiple private repositories in Cpanel?

I've tried many tutorials and documentation. Here is one of them:
https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-set-up-access-to-private-repositories/

But I'm always got this error:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
> repository.

It seems like we can only use the default name (id_rsa). I've tried this code:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "username@example"
```

It works fine. But it will generate the default (which is id_rsa). This means that we can't deploy multiple private repos, right? Because we can only use "id_rsa".

So is it possible to create an ssh key without a default name? Also, how to create multiple private repos in Cpanel?

**EDIT:**

Here is what I've done:

1. Cpanel > Terminal > Enter this code to generate SSH Key:

   ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/top25vineyards -b 4096 -C "topviney@top25vineyards.com"
2. SSH Access > Manage SSH Keys > Copy the Public Keys
3. Open the GitHub repo > Settings > Deploy Keys > Paste the keys
4. Repeat points 1-3 for the second repo. Here is the command to generate the key:

   ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/top25restaurants -b 4096 -C "topviney@top25vineyards.com"
5. Create config file on ssh folder:
   [image]
6. Test the SSH keys by doing this in the terminal:

   ssh -i ~/.ssh/top25restaurants -T git@github.com

   ssh -i ~/.ssh/top25restaurants -T git@github.com

Both return this message:
Hi <username/repo_name>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

7. Git Version Control > Create > Enter the details:
   [image]

But when I always got this error:
[image]

Am I missing something?

**EDIT 2:**

I've tried different Clone URL and it gives this error:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is it possible to create an ssh key without a default name? Also, how to create multiple private repos in Cpanel?

That is [what the documentation you are referring to mentions](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-set-up-access-to-private-repositories/#set-up-access-to-multiple-repositories).

> ### Set up access to multiple repositories
>
> To create an SSH key for each of your repositories, follow the steps outlined above.
> After you have added the keys to the remote repositories, create a local `~/.ssh/config` file to alias each of the keys to their corresponding repository names.
>
> For example, if you have two repos configured on GitHub, `testing` and `testing2`, and both your cPanel and GitHub usernames are `cptest`, create or modify the `~/.ssh/config` file with these contents:
>
> ```yaml
> Host testing.github.com
>        Hostname github.com
>        IdentityFile /home/cptest/.ssh/testing
>        User git
>
> Host testing2.github.com
>        Hostname github.com
>        IdentityFile /home/cptest/.ssh/testing2
>        User git
> ```

Compared to their documentation, I would use:

- `IdentityFile /home/cptest/...` (instead of `IdentityFile=...`)
- `User git`
- a [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)-like Host entry: `xxx.yyy.com`

That way, the URL becomes: `git clone testing.github.com:me/myRepo`

If the cPanel requires a valid protocol, use:

```
ssh://github.com-testing/me/myRepo
^^^^^^                 ^^^
(valid protocol)       (/, not :)
```

In your case:

```
ssh://top25vineyards.github.com/me/myRepo
ssh://top25vineyards.github.com/Penk13/top25vineyards
```

(to mimic an fully-qualified domain name)

Comment: I've edited my question to explain what I've done. I've followed your suggestion and it still returns an error @VonC

Comment: @penk I don't see in yuor screenshots the URL `github.com-testing`. If you want to use your `~/.ssh/config` settings, you need to use the Host entry. Not `git@github.com`, but `github.com-testing`

Comment: I've tried this command: git clone github.com-top25vineyards:Penk13/top25vineyards
It works successfully. But what I want to do is create Git Version Control based on that.
It seems like the problem is at the "Clone URL". What should be the correct Clone URL? @VonC

Comment: @penk Files/Git<sup>TM</sup> Version Control/Create: it should be the same URL, assuling your cPanel account ~/.ssh/config has a Host entry named `github.com-top25vineyard`. So directly `github.com-top25vineyards:Penk13/top25vineyards` in the "Clone URL" field.

Comment: I've tried your Clone URL and it gives an error, please see my edited question @VonC

Comment: @penk OK. I have edited the answer to address that. See the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Here is what I've tried: ssh://github.com-top25vineyards/Penk13/top25vineyards. But it still gives me an error like this: The clone URL must include a valid IP address or a fully-qualified domain name. @VonC